# Twilio Copilot - Will Sticky Sender Create a Mapping If The First Message Is Received By One of My Numbers?

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

When you are using Twilio Copilot, the service will create a mapping of which one of your numbers was used to send messages to a particular target phone number - and based on this mapping, always only send to the target phone number with the same Twilio phone number.

Will Copilot do the same thing if the first message is sent by a target phone number to one of my Twilio numbers?

For example, if `123-456-7890` (number belonging to my customer) sends a message to `999-999-9999` (one of my Twilio phone numbers), I want to ensure that every message I send to this customer going forward originates from `999-999-9999` and not any of my other Twilio numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mapping wouldn't be created by sticky sender if the first text exchanged between you and the non-Twilio number is sent by the non-Twilio number

Answer (score 0):

[Sticky sender](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages-copilot#sticky-sender) will only work as you've probably read:

> This mapping is created after the first message is sent from your
>   Messaging Service to a particular recipient.

Furthermore, there is not currently a way to intercept the Messaging Service to specify an initial number that you would like to send from.

Comment: So no mapping will be created if the first message exchanged is from my customer?

Comment: First (sticky) message comes from the service. There is just no way currently to pick a specific number to send using Messaging Service as it is done at random.

Comment: Just to translate this to English: `No`